# Reconnection of Sawtooth Validator after loosing network

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have been testing the network loss under a Sawtooth multiple nodes environment with docker.

I disconnect the validator container via `docker disconnect <validator-container>` and then connect it via `docker connect <validator-container` command

After that, all the data sent to this node remains pending.
What is the correct way to reconnect the validator after loosing the network?

Comment: Could you please add log traces to the question and give more details about the network? Need at least the information on consensus engine used, how many nodes are in the network, validator log traces of what's happening when transaction is sent.

Comment: One quick check can be to see if validators are not peering with each other. There's a known defect around max peering connections. Please set the parameter "--maximum-peer-connectivity" defined here https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/cli/sawtooth-validator.html to a maximum value. Hope this will solve your issue.